# Calcular media de las notas de un array bidimensional

Tags: javascript, array

Quiero calcular la media de la nota de un *array* bidimensional de cada alumno e ir almacenando cada media en un mismo *array*. La solución la he planteado de la siguiente manera:

```js
//Calcular media de cada alumno
function calcularMedia(alumnnos){
  //Media de cada alumno
  mediaAlumno = 0;
  //Donde se almacenan las notas medias de los alumnos
  notasAlumnos = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < alumnnos.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j < alumnos[i].length; j++) {
      mediaAlumno += alumnnos[i][j];
    }
    result = mediaAlumno / alumnnos[i].length;
    notasAlumnos.push(result);
  }

  return notasAlumnos;
}

//Imprimir notas
function imprimirNotas(notas){
  for (var i = 0; i < notas.length; i++) {
    document.write(notas[i]+"<br>");
  }
}


alumnos = [['juan',6,8,5,7],
      ['pepa',6.5,5.8,4.5,8],
      ['lola',4,5,8,3],
      ['mari',6.6,5.8,8.2,5.3],
      ['jorge',7.6,7.8,8.7,9.3]];

notas = calcularMedia(alumnos)

imprimirNotas(notas);
```

Pero no esta bien, la media no sale correcta de ningún alumno. Creo que el error viene de `result` o `mediaAlumno` a la hora de calcularlo e introducirlo en el *array* de `notasAlumnno`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tienes un par de fallos:

1.- Cuando haces `result = mediaAlumno / alumnnos[i].length;` estás dividiendo entre una longitud errónea ya que estás teniendo en cuenta el nombre del alumno. Tienes que dividir entre `alumnnos[i].length - 1`

2. Te estás olvidando de resetear la variable `mediaAlumno` a cero cuando haces el `push`.

```js
//Calcular media de cada alumno
        function calcularMedia(alumnnos){
            //Media de cada alumno
            mediaAlumno = 0;
            //Donde se almacenan las notas medias de los alumnos
            notasAlumnos = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < alumnnos.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 1; j < alumnos[i].length; j++) {
                    mediaAlumno += alumnnos[i][j];
                }
                result = mediaAlumno / (alumnnos.length - 1);
                notasAlumnos.push(result);
                mediaAlumno=0;
            }

            return notasAlumnos;
        }

        //Imprimir notas
        function imprimirNotas(notas){
            for (var i = 0; i < notas.length; i++) {
                document.write(notas[i]+"<br>");
            }
        }


        alumnos = [['juan',6,8,5,7],
                  ['pepa',6.5,5.8,4.5,8],
                  ['lola',4,5,8,3],
                  ['mari',6.6,5.8,8.2,5.3],
                  ['jorge',7.6,7.8,8.7,9.3]];

        notas = calcularMedia(alumnos)

        imprimirNotas(notas);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias kiko!!